# Can't get skin pack to work

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I spent 2 days making a skin pack, but I can't get any of my skins to show up in game.

Here's the code I have in `skins.json`:

```
{

  "geometry": "skinpacks/skins.json",
  "skins": [
    {
      "localization_name": "Herobrine",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Herobrine.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Herobrine Jr.",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "HerobrineJr.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Alexis",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "alexis.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Enderbrine",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "enderbrine.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Red Eyes Of Darkness",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": Redeyesherobrine.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Entity 303",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Entity303.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Entity 404",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Entity404.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Entity 999",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "entity999.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Error 111",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Error111.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Error",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "error.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "None",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "None.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Lick",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Lick.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Null",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Null.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Null [Female]",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "nullfemale.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Green Steve",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "GreenSteve.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Lava Steve",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "LavaSteve.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "Blue Steve",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "BlueSteve.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {     
      "localization_name": "Dark Steve",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "DarkSteve.png",
      "type": "free"
     },
    {
      "localization_name": "John",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "John.png",
      "type": "free"
     }

  ],
  "serialize_name": "Minecraft Creepypastas",
  "localization_name": "error"
}
```

And this is what it's doing: [image]

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark before `Redeyesherobrine.png "`. (You should probably also get rid of that space.)

Comment: woah really OK IMA fix it and see if it works thanks

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted then :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your JSON. You can make it easier to detect these by using a linter, such as the one at https://jsonlint.com.